# Measurement of RF Signal strength / phase difference

Tags: integrated-circuit, signal, bluetooth, phase

I would like to measure the signal relative strength and phase difference of two bluetooth (BT) receivers and I found a chip that will do exactly that, [AD8302](http://www.analog.com/en/rfif-components/detectors/ad8302/products/product.html).

But I don't know how to setup the circuit. As far as I know the BT receiver will transfer the received RF signal to UART or USB, so my question is that how can I extract the received RF signal from BT Rx at first and send it to the AD8302?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it won't work. For a start it only has inputs that are sensitive down to -60dBm because it is intended for applying to circuits after the input from the antenna has been down-converted to an IF frequency and its power raised significantly.

The second problem I see is that you want it coupled to measure the input power on the BT antenna and this is going to kill-off the BT antenna signal quite badly - in effect you are busting-up the signal you are trying to measure because this device will look like another 50 ohm coupling on the antenna.

Thirdly, the BT receiver doesn't "transfer received RF signal to UART or USB" - it transfers demodulated data and this will not be indicative of the received signal strength.

Comment: I see...so is there any way to measure strength / phase of two BT signals?? and how does iBeacon do it?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the beacon and also can you explain which two signals you wish to measure the phase of. I'm guessing the rf antenna signal but two BT modules up close are going to screw each others signals up.

Comment: I see. So even when the two BT modules are both in Rx mode are going to do some interference? I guess I will have to do more homework...Thanks for you help.